# Framework/Tool for real-time inference with large input flow using Tensorflow

Tags: streaming, machine-learning, real-time, distributed, deep-learning

I'm working on a part of a project, that detects fraud from sensors' data using deep learning. Current steps are:

1. Receiving sensors' data (I'm currently receiving data from Kafka).
2. Predicting anomalies of data (Tensorflow + PySpark structured streaming + Pandas UDF - large latency in my opinion).
3. Send the result back (to Kafka - using PySpark structured streaming).

The results are monitored by Kibana, but another team work on that part.

I don't think my solution is a good one, so I'm asking for suggestions on which platform/framework/tool should be used at each step. Any help/advice is appreciated.

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [code fragments](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), best practices/approaches etc. I've hence slightly modified your question to avoid closure. Good luck!